# Pandas DataFrame.plot resets pyplot current figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I'm trying to use pandas to plot to as specific figure, but it seems to want to make it's own figures and not use / resets pyplot's current figure.

How can I make pandas plot to the current (or better yet, and explicitly given) figure?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': list(range(1000))})
fig1 = pyplot.figure(figsize=(5, 10))
assert pyplot.gcf() is fig1 # succeeds
df.plot() # does not draw to fig1
assert pyplot.gcf() is fig1 # fails
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is quite easy. You can specify to which axes object the plot needs to refer. This can be done by getting the current handle from `ax = pyplot.gca()`, subsequently plotting to this handle. Of course, you can always plot to another handle as well using similar syntax.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':list(range(1000))})
fig1 = pyplot.figure(figsize=(5, 10))
ax = pyplot.gca()
assert pyplot.gcf() is fig1 # succeeds
df.plot(ax=ax) # draws to fig1 now
assert pyplot.gcf() is fig1 # Succeeds now, too
```

Comment: `df = pandas.DataFrame(range(1000))` results in: 
Traceback (most recent call last): ... .... ...

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: the DataFrame constructor works fine on my Pandas (0.19.2)

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.20.3 ... so I think it will be the usual case in the future. But if it is a biggie, I'll remove it from the answer, as it has nothing to do with the solution indeed

Comment: Yeah, not related to the question, I just needed some sample data. I updated the question to use your constructor to avoid any confusion

Comment: A final note on supplying `range` to `DataFrame`. This is more an issue of using python 3 versus python 2. In python 3 you'd need to convert to list first, `pd.DataFrame(list(range(1000)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly your question, but may address your need via different mechanism:

If you just want to set the figure size, you can pass `pyplot` kwargs to `df.plot`:

```
df.plot(figsize=(5, 10))
pyplot.show()
```